# Report viewer issue: Asp.Net session expired multiple server nodes

Tags: sharepoint-2013, load-balancing, reportviewer

We developed a web application using sharepoint 2013. We used rdlc reports for reports. I configured these reports in lower environments, it's working as expected. But when I deployed the code in production environment it's not working. I am getting Asp.net session is expired or could not be found. FYI, in prod we have load balancers with two server nodes and session state as inproc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is the forms authentication name attribute.

The name attribute make different applications use the same authentication in asp.net ecosystem.

It's in Portuguese, but the example can help you: https://www.rcelebrone.com/2017/09/forms-authentication-nao-mentem.html?m=1